# sed or awk - remove lines from file if expression not found

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

I have a file that contains multiple entries. the entries are seperated by 
    --
I want to remove all lines between this pattern if a certain phrase is not found within.
Example:

```
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Country
--
```

If Country is not found between -- and -- remove the complete block

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Also, is it always 6 lines consisting of "--, Company, Street, Zip Code, Country, --" for each block? Do they always appear in the same order?

Comment: how many `-- foo bar --` blocks do you have in your file? only one?

Comment: Stackoverflow is now about us writing code for you, its about helping you when your code isn't working properly. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
awk '!/Country/' RS='--\n' ORS='--\n'
```

Comment: nice usage of RS/ORS. however it will print the block "without" Country. OP means "Country not found, remove". also, it may not work if the text before the first "--" has/hasn't Country. OP just wants to remove the `--..--` part, not before not after. well, personally I think OP's requirement is not clearly explained. also the file format is not clear either.. hard to give a precise answer.

Comment: @Kent: the OP said "If Country is not found", based on the example I took that literally. I'll modify the answer if a better example is provided. It works fine without a delimiter at the beginning, at least with gawk.

Comment: I meant the beginning part (NR=1 to first "--") should be always printed, no matter those lines with or without "Country". anyway, the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '--';
print $/;

while (<>) {
    print if /\bCountry\b/;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl dataFile [>outputFile]`

Data:

```
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Elephant
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Country
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Goat
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Country
--
```

Output:

```
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Country
--
Company
Street 
Zip Code
Country
--
```